# pagesize doesn't work in Reportlab simpledocTemplate

Tags: reportlab, page-size

I am using ReportLab for generating a PDF report.
I've used SimpleDocTemplate and set pageSize = A5. but after bulding the PDF, when i open created file, the size of page is A4.

```
doc = SimpleDocTemplate(file_name, pageSize = A5)
doc.build(report)
```

I tried other page size but the created file size doesn't change and remain A4!
what should i do?

Answer (score 5):

My Problem solved!
I had just used landscape or portrait setting in additional to page size and its work!

```
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A5, portrait

doc = SimpleDocTemplate(file_name)
doc.pagesize = portrait(A5)

# Can be also written like so
# doc = SimpleDocTemplate(file_name, pagesize=portrait(A5))

doc.build(report)
```

Comment: If you solved your own problem, it's strongly recommended that you mark your own answer as the accepted answer.  This prevents the question from appearing on the list of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0):

But where from do you import **portrait()** method and **A5** value?

Comment: To answer your question... in case you still need it. I think it is from the reportlab.lib.pagesizes.