# How to set minimum size of SimpleDocTemplate?

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab, page-size

I am using python 2.7 and I am working in reportLab . But I want to set minimum size of the page `myFileFormat.pdf`. Same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13776672/pagesize-doesnt-work-in-reportlab-simpledoctemplate) but this is not answer to my question. The code is here:

```
        self.tokenFile = "myFileFormat.pdf"
        data=[["val 1"] ,["val 2"],["val 3"]]
        t=Table(data,5*[0.4*inch], 4*[0.4*inch])
        t.setStyle(TableStyle([('ALIGN',(0,0),(0,-1),'CENTER'),
                               ('BACKGROUND',(0,0),(0,0),'#D1D1D1'),
                               ]))
        self.doc = SimpleDocTemplate(self.tokenFile,pagesize=letter,
                    rightMargin=72,leftMargin=72,
                    topMargin=72,bottomMargin=60)
        self.report = []
        styleN = styles['Normal']
        self.report.append(t)
        self.doc.build(self.report)
```

I want to set page size manually. How I reach this problem?

**Edit:**

When I set `pagesize=(3*inch, 3*inch)`. It distribute the data on page into two pages. The data include only one table form having one column and four rows. I want that data static on the same page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the pagesize like you did! Just replace the argument `pagesize=letter` with `pagesize=(5*inch, 5*inch)` or whatever you want.

Comment: Data is distribute on the two page as I now tell above in Edited section?

Comment: because the data doesn't fit on one page. You have to scale the table or make the page bigger.